# Identifying REST resources by a natural key versus surrogate key

Tags: rest

I'm working on a REST API where we have a subscription resources that are identified by natural keys, which is to say, they're identified in terms of keys from other resources. Ex:

```
POST /subscriptions/user/123
POST /subscriptions/company/intel
```

The meaning of this is I want to create a subscription for user 123 or create a subscription for intel. Deleting these subscription "resources" is similar:

```
DELETE /subscriptions/user/123
DELETE /subscriptions/company/intel
```

Here's where I'm unsure of things. I'm creating subscriptions, but I'm identifying the subscriptions in terms of other natural keys: `user/123` or `company/intel`. There is no actual subscription `id`. Is this an ok way of doing things or should I create a surrogate key for each subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you have more than one subscription per user/company?  If so, then you will need a key to identify the actual subscription to delete.

If not, then I suppose that would be an OK way of designing your API.  I would hope that you generate an error on `POST` if there's already a subscription -- the user should use `PUT` to make an update, correct?

If I were to `GET /subscriptions/`, would it be a list of users and companies with subscriptions (`/subscriptions/user/123, /subscriptions/company/intel`)?

Seems reasonable.

Comment: Great question. Currently just one subscription per user/company. But I could see how we could possibly have more then one in the future (different types of subscriptions to the same thing).

Comment: Also, yes, a duplicate POST would be an error. The subscription currently has no content associated with it, so there's no need for put. But there may be content in the future. And yes, GET on `/subscriptions` would return just as you described. It just... feels wierd.

Comment: If you end up with multiple subscriptions, you could just extend your URLs.  For example, `/subscriptions/user/123/1`.  Your current `DELETE` URL would delete all of the subscriptions, but a `DELETE /subscriptions/user/123/1` would just delete that specific subscription.

Comment: This is true. Then our composite key becomes `user/123/1`. I like the simplicity of the alternative, having a globally unique subscription id: `/subscriptions/12345`. The catch is there's technically some composition here. `user/123` owns the subscription. If that user record (managed under a separate `/users` resource) goes away, then our subscription is meaningless and may as well go away.

Comment: An alternative perhaps... `/users/123/subscriptions/1`. Since the user record has an ownership over the subscription.